# Registeration & login wordpress(after successful login going to another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created registeration form for frontend and created table in wordpress for storing details.
Now I wanted login form

I have created login form

```
            <?php
            /**
             * Template Name: Login
             */

            get_header(); ?>
            <!-- Login -->
            <div class="login">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form name="login_form" method="post" action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/login_action.php">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>User Name : </td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="user_name"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password : </td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And login_action.php

```
            <?php
                include '../../../wp-load.php';
                if (isset($_POST['user_name'])&& isset($_POST['password'])) {

                $username=$_POST['user_name'];
                $password=$_POST['password'];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_profile WHERE name ='$username'";
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                foreach( $results as $result ) {
                    if($password==$result->password){
                        $status="found";
                    }
                    else{
                        $status="notfound";
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Now from this after successful login I want to  call another php file.how to call it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this after your `$status-"found"`:

```
header("Location: /path/to/file");
exit();
```

Comment: Hi..Thank you its going to another page but now my problem is
on another page there is call to get_header(); 
so it is giving error for that